# — File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg. LaTeX work

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Can you please help me to find the error? I think it's ok the first part, but i can't find the error with the equation that should be a system.

```
'''\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\title{Test di \LaTeX del Laboratorio di Comunicazione
mediante Calcolatore}
\author{Sara Pia Ciccotosto \\
\textbf{s.ciccotosto@studenti.unipi.it}}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Teorema del laboratorio}
\subsection{ L’enunciato classico}
\paragraph{Scopo di queste note `e dimostrare in modo formale un risultato noto in letterature come \textit{Teorema del Laboratorio}. Si tratta di un risultato che ha un ruolo
fondamentale nella trattazione analitica di alcuni problemi di Cauchy, come il
seguente:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = 1+x^2 y(x) \\ 
y(0)=0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}'''
```

this is the output:

```
Runaway argument?
{Scopo di queste note `e dimostrare in modo formale un risultato noto\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@xdblarg.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> "./test lcmc.tex"
                     
?
```

and in "Error, warnings and badboxes" is written "File ended while scanning use of @xdblarg"

Thank you!

Comment: You open the parenthesis at `\paragraph{`, but never close it

Comment: .... also `\paragraph{}` is not to set whole paragraphs, it is just for the headline

Comment: This was easy to spot with some syntax check and attention to matching {}, please refrain to ask questions that can be resolved by little investigation.